# Google Fusion Tables: Two layers, one with style

Tags: styles, layer, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create a map using Google Fusion Tables with two layers, one of which I want to add a style to. I also have multiple columns, and I want to switch between these columns using a drop-down menu. So far I managed to do the latter, but I'm stuck trying to add a second layer.

The map I have now shows the ratio of girls:boys in schools in the 170 districts in Ghana. With the drop down menu I can switch between primary school and junior high. Now I want to add a layer with the regional borders.

In the documentation I saw this:

> You can use the Maps API to add up to five Fusion Tables layers to a
>   map, one of which can be styled with up to five styling rules.

Which is pretty much exactly what I want, but I also keep the drop-down menu. I've recently started using Fusion Tables and was hoping someone could help me.

The ID of the layer I want to add: 1_0rcifQnnNpLV1VjTPyzDZSF3LHp-7rowzrXM78

And the code of the working map:

PS: I'm a total newbie and used [this map made by the Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/news/datablog/interactive/2012/sep/13/hate-crime-map-england-wales) as a basis. I got rid of everything I didn't think I needed, but there might be some unnecessary stuff left in the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<head>

                <title>Gender Parity Index | Education | 2011</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

                            <style type="text/css">
  body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  #map_canvas { height: 600px; width:575px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" id="script">

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(7.972198, -0.716284);
var zoom = 7;
var legend_width = '150px';
var tableid = '12GLQaH4wvwByxBk4W7UHkJTr99vsxymCTYHmkXs';
var location_column = 'geometry';
var colors = ['#CA0020','#F4A582','#F7F7F7','#92C5DE','#0571B0']; 
var columns = {
  'Gender parity index at primary education': [
    {
      'min': 0.6,
      'max': 0.8,
      'color': '#CA0020'
    },
    {
      'min': 0.8,
      'max': 0.95,
      'color': '#F4A582'
    },
    {
      'min': 0.95,
      'max': 1.05,
      'color': '#F7F7F7'
    },
    {
      'min': 1.05,
      'max': 1.2,
      'color': '#92C5DE'
    }
  ],
  'Gender parity index at junior high school education': [
     {
      'min': 0.6,
      'max': 0.8,
      'color': '#CA0020'
    },
    {
      'min': 0.8,
      'max': 0.95,
      'color': '#F4A582'
    },
    {
      'min': 0.95,
      'max': 1.05,
      'color': '#F7F7F7'
    },
    {
      'min': 1.05,
      'max': 1.2,
      'color': '#92C5DE'
    },
    {
      'min': 1.2,
      'max': 1.6,
      'color': '#0571B0'
    }

  ]
}

var map, layer, geocoder;

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var style = [ { stylers: [ { invert_lightness: true } ] },{ featureType: "road.highway", stylers: [ { hue: "#00e5ff" } ] },{ featureType: "poi.park", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },{ featureType: "landscape.natural", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" } ] },{ featureType: "water", stylers: [ { color: "#080808" } ] },{ featureType: "landscape.natural", stylers: [ { color: "#202020" } ] },{ featureType: "administrative.province", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" } ] },{ featureType: "administrative.locality", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" } ] },{ featureType: "administrative.country", elementType: "labels", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" } ] },{
  featureType: 'road',
  elementType: 'all',
  stylers: [
  { saturation: -99 }
  ]
  } ];

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
    map: map,
    name: 'Styled Map'
  });

  map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('map-style');


  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: location_column,
      from: tableid
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);

  init_selectmenu();
  addStyle(getKey());


}



function getKey() {
  for(key in columns) {
    return key;
  }
}

// Initialize the drop-down menu
function init_selectmenu() {
  var selectmenu = document.getElementById('selector');
  for(column in columns) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', column);
    option.innerHTML = column;
    selectmenu.appendChild(option);
  }
}

function addStyle(column) {
  var defined_styles = columns[column];
  var styles = new Array();

  for(defined_style in defined_styles) {
    var style = defined_styles[defined_style];
    styles.push({
      where: generateWhere(column, style.min, style.max),
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: style.color,
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        strokeOpacity: 0.50,
        strokeColor: "#f3f3f3"
      }
    });

  }

  layer.set('styles', styles);
  updateLegend(column);
}

// Create the where clause
function generateWhere(column_name, low, high) {
  var whereClause = new Array();
  whereClause.push("'");
  whereClause.push(column_name);
  whereClause.push("' >= ");
  whereClause.push(low);
  whereClause.push(" AND '");
  whereClause.push(column_name);
  whereClause.push("' < ");
  whereClause.push(high);
  return whereClause.join('');
}

// Create the legend with the corresponding colors
function updateLegend(column) {
  var legendDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var legend = new Legend(legendDiv, column);
  legendDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].pop();
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(legendDiv);
}

// Generate the content for the legend
function Legend(controlDiv, column) {
  controlDiv.style.padding = '10px';
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  controlUI.style.width = legend_width;
  controlUI.title = 'Legend';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';

  controlText.innerHTML = legendContent(column);
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
}

function legendContent(column) {
  var defined_styles = columns[column];

  // Generate the content for the legend using colors from object
  var controlTextList = new Array();
  controlTextList.push('<p><b>');
  controlTextList.push(column);
  controlTextList.push('</b></p>');
  for(defined_style in defined_styles) {
    var style = defined_styles[defined_style];
    controlTextList.push('<div style="background-color: ');
    controlTextList.push(style.color);
    controlTextList.push('; height: 20px; width: 20px; margin: 3px; float: left;"></div>');
    controlTextList.push(style.min);
    controlTextList.push(' to ');
    controlTextList.push(style.max);
    controlTextList.push('<br style="clear: both;"/>');
  }

  controlTextList.push('<br />');
  return controlTextList.join('');
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize();">

<select onchange="addStyle(this.value);" id="selector" style="font-size: 16px"></select>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

                        </div>
    <script>
        // send the query string to the iFrame
        (function() {
            var interactive = jQ('#interactive iframe');
            if (interactive.length > 0) {
                var qs = window.location.search;
                interactive[0].src = interactive[0].src + qs;
            }
        })();
    </script>
</div>
            <div id="related">

</script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the second layer at the end of your `initialize()` method like that:

```js
function initialize() {
    // ... all the other stuff ...

    borderLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1_0rcifQnnNpLV1VjTPyzDZSF3LHp-7rowzrXM78'
        }
    });
    borderLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

See the working example of [your code with the second layer on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/K9EQQ/).

Comment: Thanks Odi! That's almost perfect, except now the border disappears when I switch the option in the drop down menu.

Comment: I see, the styling overrides the other layer. A simple solution would be to add the "border layer" each time you change the map. I updated my example so the layer is set (using `setBorderLayer()`) each time the `addStyle()` function is called: http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/K9EQQ/

Comment: That's great Odi, thank you. There is still a problem though; when going back and forth between the two options, the regional borders suddenly disappear after switching about four times. Any idea what's causing that and how to fix it?

Comment: Ah yes I know why, got a little error in there. You may only add up to five layers to a map, and I accidently added a new border layer on each change. Now the code is fixed and only one border layer is created.